# WNDPROC declaration problem, converting from C to C++

Tags: c++, wndproc

I am converting a program from C to C++. I have the compiler set to use the __fastcall calling convention by default.

I used to have a declaration line as follows:

```
INT32 PASCAL graph_window_handler(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

Later I have:

```
wndclass.lpfnWndProc    = graph_window_handler;
```

This all compiled and worked under C. But under C++ I get all sorts of complaints form the compiler about the second line of code. I guess I need to change the original declaration to something involving WNDPROC, perhaps with a _cdecl thrown in? With or without the INT32? but it seems that every variation I try still gets complained about. What should the declaration look like such that the second line does not get complained about? - cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573%28VS.85%29.aspx) it should look like the following:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK graph_window_handler(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

And if you'll check `WinUser.h` you'll see that `WNDPROC` typedef'ed as follows:

```
typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK* WNDPROC)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

Comment: Thanks for that.
I have no idea how/why "LRESULT CALLBACK" is equivalent/castable to "WNDPROC" but heck, its working, so that will do me.